# Sorting the Addressess of the pointers in a dynamically allocated array of class

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers

I've created a dynamically allocated array of a class.

```
class AlienShip
{
    public:
       int DAMAGE;
  ..........
};

AlienShip * ships = new AlienShip[N];
```

Where `N` is between 2 and 50 inclusively. After initialization of each element, I want to sort the array in the decreasing value of `DAMAGE` in each of `ships`.

I implemented a simple bubble sort to do the same. However, *instead of moving whole objects around, I want to move the addresses of pointers*. I did something like this:

```
....
if(ships[j].DAMAGE < ships[j+1].DAMAGE)
      swap( ships + j, ships + j + 1)
....
```

But it shows a compile-time error, saying it didn't find any matching function `swap`. I think the swap() is defined as a template in `<cstdlib>` then why does it not work?

EDIT: I discovered that sorting the pointer address does NOT necessarily sorts the array.  But I wrote a swap function to sort some pointer address but it didn't have any effect.

```
mySwap(int* a, int* b){
    int *tmp;
    tmp = a, a = b, b = tmp;
}
```

I wanted to swap the address of a and b. So that *b refers to previous *a. But it didn't work. I wonder why?

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: @JohnFilleau [Error Message](https://pastebin.com/rnXj6hwC).     The link will expire in 1 month time from the time of posting of this comment.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to some website where the error message will self destruct, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63870442/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have an array of `AlienShip`s, and you want to sort on the `DAMAGE` variable of each, then use `std::sort` with a custom comparison function. You don't need to sort pointers. You have one pointer (to the start of your array). Using that pointers, you get each `AlienShip`.

If you want to swap a pair of `AlienShip`s, you can take advantage of the fact that you should have a default assignment operator for your class.

```
swap(AlienShip& a, AlienShip& b) {
    AlienShip temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

But instead of having a pointer to dynamically acquired memory using `new`, you should either statically allocate memory (using `std::array`) or dynamically allocate memory (using `std::vector`). Then you can use `std::sort` in `<algorithm>` to easily sort your array.

Example follows:

```
#include <algorithm>  // for std::sort
#include <functional> // for std::greater
#include <array>      // for std::array
#include <iostream>   // for std::cout and std::ostream
#include <vector>     // for std::vector

constexpr int num_alien_ships = 10;

class AlienShip
{
public:

    AlienShip(int damage)
        : damage_(damage)
    {}

    inline const int& damage() const {
        return damage_;
    }

private:
    int damage_;
};

// This operator<< overload is provided for convenience in showing that
// the ships are actually sorted below
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const AlienShip& alien_ship) {
    os << alien_ship.damage();
    return os;
}

// If you define a greater-than operator for your AlienShips,
// then you can use the std::greater template from <algorithm>
// to sort from big damage to small damage
bool operator>(const AlienShip& a, const AlienShip& b) {
    return a.damage() > b.damage();
}

int main() {
    std::array<AlienShip, num_alien_ships> alien_array = { 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5, 0 };
    std::sort(alien_array.begin(), alien_array.end(),
        [](const AlienShip& a, const AlienShip& b) { return a.damage() > b.damage();  }
    );

    std::cout << "Result of sorting alien_array using a custom lambda:\n";
    for (const AlienShip& a : alien_array) {
        std::cout << a << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Result of sorting alien_vector using std::greater:\n";
    std::vector<AlienShip> alien_vector = { 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 };
    std::sort(alien_vector.begin(), alien_vector.end(), std::greater<AlienShip>());
    for (const AlienShip& a : alien_vector) {
        std::cout << a << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Use the overloaded `operator>` function to define ordering for your `AlienShip`s if it makes sense for them to be sorted by `damage_`. If that order only makes sense in the context of this single sort operation, stick to the lambda.

If you *really* want to sort by moving around pointers, them you need an actual array of pointers:

```
AlienShip* alien_ship_ptr[10];
std::for_each(std::begin(alien_ship_ptr), std::end(alien_ship_ptr), [](AlienShip*& asp){ asp = new AlienShip; });
```

After populating your array of pointers, then you can sort them using the methods described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can only swap variables.  `ships + j` is not a variable reference.

Answer (score 0):

ships have AlienShip type and j probably is int in your case,
try this **swap(ships[j],ships[j+1])**

Comment: swap(ships[j], ships[j+1]) will swap the values referenced by the pointers there. I want to swap the address of the pointers. Is there a way to do that?